# What is the use of RelativeLayout.TRUE

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

So I have this code

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionRules = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

What is the use of that RelativeLayout.TRUE in there? What if I set it to false?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set it to `FALSE`, it is as if the rule was not there. The default behavior for all those `boolean`-style rules is `FALSE`.

Comment: so what's the use of this method --> addRule(int verb);? Does it mean it wont mean anything? Sorry if my question didn't make sense but I really didn't understand.

Comment: Perfect answer  #CommonsWare SIR

Comment: @JudeMaranga: `addRule(foo)` is the same as `addRule(foo, RelativeLayout.FALSE)`. As to why, while *you* happen to be hard-coding a value, do not assume that everyone will in all cases. Allowing the two-parameter `addRule()` to be used for `boolean`-type rules is a convenience, particularly for those where the `TRUE`/`FALSE` value is determined dynamically.

Comment: But I mean, what is the purpose of addRule if you just set it to RelativeLayout.FALSE?

Comment: @JudeMaranga: Once again, convenience, presumably.

Answer (score 1):

It's used for `addRule(int verb, int subject)` function.

The default values is `TRUE`. If you set it to `FALSE`, it will disable rule.

And according to [RelativeLayout.java#1408](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/RelativeLayout.java#L1408): `public void addRule(int verb)` called `addRule(verb, TRUE)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can change paramether with xml file and java file

xml:

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >
   </RelativeLayout>
```

and in java file:

```
 RelativeLayout.LayoutParams positionRules = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
    positionRules.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
```

> If true, makes the right and buttom edge of this view match the right
>   and buttom edge of   the parent.
>   else do nothing.